# Lambda authorizer not granting permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, authorization, serverless-framework

for a learning project I set up a Lambda authorizer which does a lookup in DynamoDB table $DYNAMODB_TABLE_PROJECTS to determine access permissions to another table $    DYNAMODB_TABLE_TASKS. It returns a policy, which is not working as expected.

The permission error looks as follow:

```
 An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Query operation:
User: arn:aws:sts::984689749767:assumed-role/task-estimator-backend-dev-eu-central-1-lambdaRole/task-estimator-backend-dev-taskGetAll
is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: 
arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:984689749767:table/task-estimator-backend-dev-tasks 
because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action
```

What I tried so far

- Making sure the policy is valid (via Policy Simulator)
- Making sure the policy is evaluated by introducing deliberate errors
- Granting all permissions by default, and changing the generated policy to DENY. Again, no effect

What is happening between the authorizer lambda and the lambda I want to grant permissions to is a bit black-boxy to me. From the examples I studied it's not clear to me what piece of information I'm missing.

My configuration looks as follow:

**Serverless.yml**

```
  provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: 'eu-central-1'
  runtime: python3.9
  memorySize: 128
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE_TASKS: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-tasks
    DYNAMODB_TABLE_PROJECTS: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-projects
  httpApi:
    authorizers:
      customAuthorizer:
        type: request
        functionName: authorizerFunc
```

**api.yml**

```
  taskGetAll:
    handler: functions/tasks.get_tasks
    events:
      - httpApi:
          method: get
          path: /tasks/get
          authorizer:
            name: customAuthorizer
  
  # Authorization
  authorizerFunc:
    handler: functions/auth.get_permissions
    role: authRole
```

**authRole** assigned to authorizer lambda, which gives permission to do the initial table lookup in $DYNAMODB_TABLE_PROJECTS:

```
  authRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: authRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: myPolicyName
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow 
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:GetItem
                  - dynamodb:Query
                Resource:
                  - Fn::GetAtt:
                      - DynamoTableProjects
                      - Arn 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource: "*"
```

**Policy document**, which is generated by the lambda authorizer that is supposed to grant access to read from $DYNAMODB_TABLE_TASKS:

```
"principalId":"59e30e90",
"policyDocument":{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:Query"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/task-estimator-backend-dev-tasks",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/task-estimator-backend-dev-tasks/index/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "execute-api:Invoke",
            "execute-api:ManageConnections"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd appreciate any help I get, any questions asked that could bring me back on track.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If I understood correctly, the returned policy is only applicable to

> "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"

i.e. it is determining which endpoint URL can be called, but does not change permissions of the lambda behind the API gateway.

I changed the API to e.g. {authUrl}/{projecId}/items/get and consider these path parameters in the policy document to allow invokation only for specific projectIds based on the provided authUrl (think: Link-sharing, where URLs are associated with a project, and admin/contributer/viewer URLs exist).